# 1 index for 2 kinds of queries below possible in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
select xx from tablexx where type in (1,3) and last<current-interval 30 second;

select xx from tablexx where type=1;
```

If create index on (type,last),the first one won't use index.

If create index on (last,type),the second one won't use index.

As for data type,which is can be seen from the example,type: int unsigned,last: datetime

Answer (score 1):

In the first query, MySQL is going to look for an index on 'last' because it is an inequality.  I would then expect it to have to iterate over all records with 'last

I would expect you'd get just as good performance with two separate indexes, one on 'last' (for the first query) and one on 'type' (for the second query).

The 'EXPLAIN' command can be really helpful for analysing this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The second query, having only `type = 1` in the where clause, only needs and index on `type`, not on `(type, last)`.

MySQL *should* pick the most specific index for your query, so creating an index just covering `type` should be used for the second one, but not the first one.

Comment: If this still doesn't solve your problem (started with stackoverflow.com/questions/998812), a reorganization of your tables might be necessary. Again, providing the full schema would help here.

Answer (score 0):

You stated "If create index on (type,last),the first one won't use index." Are you sure about this? I was under the impression this is exactly the circumstance under which a covering index would execute. 
EDIT: Unless of course there's a selectivity problem with the data - if most records have type 1 or 3 then the optimizer wouldn't use the index (regardless of whether it was a basic or composite index).